# Laravel Ajax on Update data getting Success Message on same Page

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to update data using Ajax in Laravel, my data is being updated successfully but when i click on update it's success message is showing on next page, i want it to show message and updated data on same Page without loading page.

**Laravel Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
        $teacher->efirst = $request->efirst;
        $teacher->esecond = $request->esecond;
        $teacher->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'esecond has been updated'
        ]);
    }
```

**AJAX function: Update.Js,**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $("#update-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers/" + $('#update-id').attr("value"),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                    let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
                     teacher.forEach(item => { $(`[name=${item[0]}]`).val('item[1]'); });
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**view:**
it contains table to show list of teacher with edit, and form under table with update button.
My data is being updated, but i don't want page reload. maybe something to do with append?

Comment: can you please update form html tags?

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: I just wanted to see your form tag. what are the props you used in your '<form>' tag?

Comment: you can change your `<input type="submit" ..../>` to <input type="button"..../>` and instead of using `submit()` event use 'onClick()' event,

Comment: i tried this: $("form").on('submit',function(e):: but not being submitted now

Answer (score 1):

if you want to refresh the data 
you can make this

```
var table =  $('#tableId');
table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

this command can reload the data, 
 also in your view,
 you can make the button

```
type="button"
```

or add to the form

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Comment: did you try to put the message into session?